# Hide first cell behind navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to hide the first cell behind the navigation bar when loaded and can only be seen when the tableview is scrolled down.

Comment: I would recommend to add a special subview for your purpose, which could be a subview of a UIScrollView, implement several delegate method would meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide first cell behind navigation bar by setting its `contentInset` in `viewDidLoad` method as shown below:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -44, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

After that you can use `scrollViewDidScroll` to detect if user scroll `tableView` and you can set `contentInset` again one user scroll down as shown in below code:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        if lastContentOffset < -55{

            if !tablevieSetTo0 {
                self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 65, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
                tablevieSetTo0 = true
            }
        }
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

And below is complete code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0
    var tablevieSetTo0 = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -44, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            if lastContentOffset < -55{

                if !tablevieSetTo0 {
                    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 65, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
                    tablevieSetTo0 = true
                }
            }
        }
        self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
}
```

Project [sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=10738801608416918648) for more Info.